# Get Meridian from time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have following time **"Mon Jun 22 03:45:24 PDT 2015"** how can I get Meridian using Javascript.
I was doing this:

```
d= Mon Jun 22 03:45:24 PDT 2015;
var hours = d.getHours();
var meridiem = "AM";

if (d.getHours() > 12) {
   hours = d.getHours() % 12;
   if (hours == 2) {
      hours = 12;
   }
   meridiem = "PM";
}
```

But its not working in IE 8.

Comment: I don't get what `d= Mon Jun 22 03:45:24 PDT 2015;` is supposed to do. That isn't even legal JavaScript code.

Comment: In IE 8 I am getting Nan so I used following method function convertDateFromISO(s) { s = s.split(/\D/); return new Date(Date.UTC(s[0], --s[1] || '', s[2] || '', s[3] || '', s[4] || '', s[5] || '', s[6] || '')) } 
which gives me this date "Mon Jun 22 03:45:24 PDT 2015"

Comment: How exactly are you getting `NaN`? If you want the current date you can do `new Date()`. If you already have date in ISO format, you can parse it directly using `new Date("Mon Jun 22 03:45:24 PDT 2015")`. Are you saying using `(new Date("Mon Jun 22 03:45:24 PDT 2015")).getTime()` gives you `NaN` in IE8? (Sorry can't reproduce, don't have IE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you define

```
d= Mon Jun 22 03:45:24 PDT 2015;
```

actually it is nothing in javascript 
some browser more intelligent some not, it's up to the browser behaviour 
you have to tell javascript like that

```
  function getCurrentTime() {
                var currentTime;
                // here we can give our date
                var currentDate = new Date("Mon Jun 22 03:45:24 PDT 2015");
                // OR we can define like that also for current date
                // var currentDate = new Date();
                var hour = currentDate.getHours();
                var meridiem = hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
                currentTime = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1) + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes() + meridiem;
                return currentTime;
            }
```

Comment: As I do like the code, an explanation for this [code-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques) will be appreciated.

Comment: @A1rPun you are right and i appreciate your suggestion but i didn't find anything to write at that moment might be i am wrong, but posted user should mark as a answer because it's working :)

Comment: You could explain why it isn't working for the OP, or what he can improve. To quote @casperOne in the answer I linked: `We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day.`

Answer (score 3):

We can get time in 12 hour format, including the meridian by using the [Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) method with a US English argument which returns the time in AM/PM. Without the argument `'en-US'` date will return the format it deems appropriate for your timezone.

From there we can utilise the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method to get the last two characters of the timestamp using a negative index:

```
var d = new Date("Mon Jun 22 03:45:24 PDT 2015")
  // US English uses 12-hour time with AM/PM
var timestamp = d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
  // timestamp → "03:45:24 AM"
var meridian = timestamp.slice(-2);
  // meridian → "AM"
```

One liner for brevity:

```
var meridian = new Date("Mon Jun 22 03:45:24 PDT 2015").toLocaleTimeString().slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for JavaScript `Date` object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype#Methods), there is no method for directly getting 12-hour hours and therefore no method for getting am/pm directly from the `Date` object.

You *can* get hours (24-hour format) which you can use to get 12-hour hours and am/pm. (You've already done it but I don't understand what you're trying to do in your code.)

This would be one way to do this.

This code is inspired by @tinka.

```
var d = new Date("Mon Jun 22 03:45:24 PDT 2015");
var h = (d.getHours() + 11) % 12 + 1; //Courtesy @tinka
var m = h > 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
```

And you can always add methods to `Date.prototype` if you're gonna be using them repeatedly.

```
Date.prototype.getHours12 = function() {
   return (this.getHours() + 11) % 12 + 1; // edited.
}

Date.prototype.getMeridiem = function() {
   return this.getHours() > 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
}
```

It should work on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

With Date object:

```
getMeridiem(date: Date) {
   return date.toLocaleTimeString().split(' ')[1];
}
```